# add items to listview dynamically android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

How to take data that was typed in EditText and by clicking "submit" in that window should add it to previous activity listview items?
What I need to do is:

1. Creating EditText and submit button
2. Creating listview in same Activity
3. By clicking submit button it should display it in listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new class with a `public static` variable that holds the data which was submitted when you pressed the button. Then override the `onResume()` event of your previous activity, which will be called when you return to the activity, and add the data into the listview.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class GlobalVariable
{
    public static ArrayList<Object> exampleList = new ArrayList<Object>();
}
```

Then in your code:

```
GlobalVariable.exampleList.add(exampleObject);
```

Then in your previous activity:

```
protected void onResume()
{
    // Put code to add to listview here
    super.onResume();
}
```