# How to add ListView items on button click using adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

How to take data that was typed in EditText and by clicking "submit" in that window should add it to previous activity listview items?
What I need to do is:

1. Creating EditText and submit button
2. Creating listview in same Activity
3. By clicking submit button it should display it in listview.

I saw this similar question here:[add items to listview dynamically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826148/add-items-to-listview-dynamically-android)

But i couldn't understand the answer.Somebody please explain how to do this.

Comment: what to implement till now post it first?

Comment: @SimplePlan I did until the button click.Now i need to know how the text entered in the EditText can be added to ListView.

Comment: then show me your ListView Adapter code.

Comment: Retrieve edittext value in string and just add this string value to List<String> arraylist.

Comment: and then called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just do the following :
Prepare your xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addItem"
     android:hint="Add a new item to List View" />

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/addItem"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:text="Add" /> 

  <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/editText" >
  </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity looks like following :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    Button addButton;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("First Item - added on Activity Create");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `String Arraylist` and initialize it

```
    ArrayList<String> str1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Add some values on it

```
     str1.add("First Row");
     str1.add("Second Row");
     str1.add("Third Row");
     str1.add("Fourth Row");
     str1.add("Fifth Row");
```

Then set `Adapter` to `ListView`

```
adapter=new ListAdapter(this,str1);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then add your `EditText` text into str1 and then called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` like

```
str1.add(edit_message.getText().toString());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try to add this code into `Button onclick()`

**Demo Output:**

[image]

Comment: i see ur above image..... but do u know how to open new activity when u click on "new item"...  if u know then pls tell me

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> dataList = new Arraylist ();
```

So `On clicking of button, you need to add the new data item into your data arraylist.`

For this first take the value entered in edittext and store in a string.

```
String editedValue = yourEditText.getText.toString();
```

Then we need to add this in our datalist.

Like

```
dataList.add(editedValue);
```

And then just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It will work.