# How to add two view in single listview dynamically

Tags: android

I just wanna do an android application which has dynamic listview with two layouts.(i.e) I've an listview with one custom view & one Textview called a "ADD".If i click that textview "ADD", an dialog should open which gets some inputs from the user & those should be populated in the Custom listview as name1 & 11111.

If again i click ADD textview, it should again gets values from user as for example name2 & 22222 that should populate in the listview as

name1  11111

name2  22222

ADD

It simply means, should add a textview at the end of each updated listview in android.How could i do that?Thanks in advance.Below is my code.in this,i couldn't able to make click listener on that ADD Textview & second value of that arraylist is not populated well.

Code:
http://pastebin.com/4UvKc63G

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22145297/1777090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add name into item list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and you need to Include Add button into listveiw keep it in parent layout

Comment: ok how could i implement this?How can i keep that textview in parent layout? Any code is much appreciated.

Comment: Please go through with below links it full-fill your requirements http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/

Comment: please up if it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Just below the custom list view you add your testview or button. It will handle dynamically if your listview increases.